# Drupal 5: Flag module - display user flagged items in a block

Tags: drupal, user-interface, e-commerce

I am aiming to get a list of the **current user's flagged items in a block** which I can use in my node.tpl.php The functionality required is a "comparison list" of products.

Can anyone with experience of the [flag module](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/flag) in **D5** point me in the right direction? I essentially want to be able to say:

```
<?php print $all_current_user_flags ?>
```

Is there a predefined function for this or will I have to get it out of the database manually? I haven't managed to find [much in the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/296955) about this, and am I bit stuck as to what is the best course of action.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit:* to anyone still reading this, I've moved over to the [session favourites](http://drupal.org/project/session_favorites) module as it lets anonymous users build a list of favourites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://mrphp.com.au/code/project/drupal/drupal-5/how-display-view-block) works:

```
<h3>Comparison List</h3>
<?php print views_build_view('page',views_get_view('flag_bookmarks'),$args,true,10,$page); ?>
```